# Using nameof to get a setter method name in c#

Tags: c#, nameof

Is it possible to get a setter method name using the new `nameof` operator?

```
public object Foo { get; set; }

public void Test()
{        
    var myMethod = GetType().GetMethod("set_Foo");       
}
```

I guess  `GetType().GetMethod("set_" + nameof(Foo))` could work but is there something more straightforward?

Comment: Can you provide any more context as to why you need to use reflection to achieve this? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Probably you must use GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Foo)).SetMethod ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `nameof` to get the setter method name directly.

You can combine it with reflection to get the property and use `PropertyInfo.SetMethod` to get the setter:

```
MethodInfo setterMethod = GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Foo)).SetMethod;
string setterName = setterMethod.Name;
```

Comment: The question says using the `nameof` method.

Comment: 2DavidG >"Is it possible to get a setter method name using the new nameof operator ?" yes it possible, but right way is to use GetProperty and not GetMethod

Comment: @DavidG question body also says *is there something more straightforward?*

Comment: @DavidG This *is* using `nameof`. This was my answer too, but I was beaten to it.

Comment: (though you probably want to use `SetMethod.Name`)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the remarks, I included them in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It suits well my usecase.

Answer (score -1):

Something like -

```
var type = typeof(Test).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault().GetAccessors(false);
```

where `Test` is the `type` with a `property` `S3` of type `string`.

Comment: The question says using the `nameof` method.